# How to uninstall Nautilus and its Dependencies on WSL?

Tags: apt, package-management, nautilus, dependencies, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was taking a terminal course, when the teacher used Nautilus (he uses Ubuntu on his laptop), so I did too. However I use WSL and it seems I can use different commands to manage files. However, Nautilus installed a lot of dependencies I'll not use. I tried to follow [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708701/using-apt-get-to-remove-packages-and-dependencies?newreg=5954bd9e0ab94165805380c90726f6fb). However, it worked with some dependencies, I still have most of them.

Comment: Try `sudo apt autoremove`. That's a general suggestion, since "*most of them*" is too vague to offer specific advice.

Comment: Autoremove will only remove files that are unnecessary and are not called by any other programs.

Answer (score 1):

As @user535733 said, `sudo apt autoremove` will remove *unecessary* packages and files. It will *not* remove Nautilus, because that is considered to be detrimental if you use a GUI. Nautilus is the application that allows you to graphically view, edit, and move files. I do not recommend removing Nautilus.

To remove nautilus, run `sudo apt-get update` and then run `sudo apt-get remove nautilus` and *then* you can run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove Nautilus dependencies. Only dependencies that are called by Nautilus and only by Nautilus will be removed by the `autoremove` command. Again, I do not recommend removing Nautilus.

Comment: Good advice in general, but on WSL, it's just fine to remove Nautilus.  As the OP mentioned, it's not installed by default, and Windows Explorer is the primary way of browsing files (even those in WSL).